# CKEditor: convert multiple p tags into single p tag on Paste

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

When pasting paragraphs from Word to CKEditor, I get a p tag per each paragraph. Is it possible to convert multiple p tags into one and insert 2 line breaks to separate them (except, of course if it's just one p tag)? E.g.

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p> 
<p>Nullam egestas sodales dolor eget laoreet.</p>
<p>Curabitur et risus</p>

<h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>

<p>Nullam egestas</p>
<p>Curabitur et</p>
```

Convert to:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br><br>

Nullam egestas sodales dolor eget laoreet.<br><br>

Curabitur et risus</p>

<h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>

<p>Nullam egestas<br><br>

Curabitur et</p>
```

I'd also like to keep the empty lines after the br tags to make the code cleaner as shown above. Can anyone help?

Comment: you could possibly do a check for on update to replace </p><p> to <br/><br/>, but unless there is a specific reason for it, I'd recommend against this. With CSS, the <p> sections can be uniformly styled. To be fair, when I started out I did this too, mostly because <p> isn't styled the way I want out of the box but plopping 2 <br />s did it for me, but if you do p { margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: 1em;} or something similar, you might be where you are really wanting to be, not sure.

Comment: let word_str as pasting paragraphs from Word, follow my code `word_str.split("</p><p>").join("<br /><br />"); // the result pasting to CKEditor`

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your data as you want, on specific event

e.g. `paste`, `afterPasteFromWord`, `afterPaste`

`CKEDITOR.instances["textarea1"].on('paste', function (evt) {
    evt.data.dataValue = evt.data.dataValue.replace("\n","<br><br>")
});`